# How do I pass output of tf.encode_jpeg() into tf.train.BytesList()?

Tags: jpeg, tensorflow2.0, tfrecord

In Tensorflow 2.2, how do I take the output from `tf.encode_jpeg()` (which is a tensor of type string) and convert it into bytes that would be accepted as input by `tf.train.BytesList(value=[xxx])`?  Eventually, I want to add this to a TFRecord.  When I try running some basic code (shown below in the error), I get the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-25-0a8dec1885d5> in <module>
      4 x = np.array([[[1],[2]],[[3],[4]]], dtype=np.uint8)
      5 x = tf.io.encode_jpeg(x)
----> 6 x = tf.train.BytesList(value=[x])
      7 

TypeError: <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, 
numpy=b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x01,\x01,\x 
has type tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor, but expected one of: bytes
```

I've already tried using `tf.compat.as_bytes` to convert the tensor to bytes, but that just creates a different error.
P.S. Is it foolish to combine tf.encode_jpeg() and tf.train.BytesList()?

Comment: Before passing x to tf.train.BytesList try to convert a tensor to string with x = x.numpy(). In TF 1.x was used .eval() to get value of tensor and in TF2.X .numpy() does basically the same thing. At least in this way I managed to compress my tfrecords to 5 times smaller space.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tf.io.serialize_tensor(image)` to convert to bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))): #<-Add this. 
     value = value.numpy() #<-Add this. BytesList won't unpack a string from an EagerTensor.
return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))
```